# Constructing Farey sequences inductively

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, fractions, farey-sequences

Objective: I'd like to prove that $F_{n+1}$ (the Farey sequence of order $n+1$) is obtained form the Farey sequence $F_n$ of order $n$ by adding all fractions of the form  $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ when $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$ are neighbours in $F_n$ and $b+d=n+1$.

Problem: I managed to show that $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac{c}{d}$, but I also need to show that $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ is of the right form (i.e. that it's a completely reduced fraction), so my question is:
how do I show that $gcd(a+c, b+d)=1$?

Comment: The version of Farey sequences that I learned just defined F_{n+1} that way and derived all the other properties from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neighbours $\frac{a}{b} \lt \frac{c}{d}$ in the Farey sequence satisfy

$$ bc - ad = 1$$

Now $ b(a+c) - a(b+d) = bc - ad = 1$.

Thus $\text{gcd}(a+c, b+d) = 1$.

Comment: +1: For the sake of completeness I recommend that the OP should prove that the identity $bc-ad=1$ holds for the other "newly created" pairs of adjacent fractions as well.

Comment: @sssuuusssuccc: You are welcome!

Comment: I wonder how many on this site know of the historical significance of your user-name Aryabhata. :)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I would like to say ZERO, but that would just be an invention of mine. :-P

Comment: @Aryabhata . It took me 30 minutes, but  I finally "got it". Kudos.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth remarking that this and many related properties of Farey sequences have very beautiful geometric proofs using Pick's formula and related techniques - see my [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39671/242) and its links.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Farey sequence of order $n$ as the sequnce of fractions occurring in-order traversal of the [Stern-Brocot tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern-Brocot_tree), while not descending into branches whose denominator exceeds $n$. Here one only encounters completely reduced fractions, so that is in order. The descendants of a node in the tree are obtained by adding to its numerator and denominator those of its first *ancestor* in the tree that is on the proper side of it (taking $\frac01$ and $\infty=\frac10$ as ultimate ancestors to ensure there is always one on either side).

If a fraction between $0$ and $1$ has denominator $n+1$ then its parent in the Stern-Brocot tree has a smaller denominator, and the first ancestor of the parent in the proper direction was next to in in the in-order traversal up to level $n$, which explains why you always get $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ between $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$. The relation $bc-ad=1$ holds whenever either $\frac ab$ is the first ancestor of $\frac cd$ less than it or $\frac cd$ is the first ancestor of $\frac ab$ greater than it; this follows by induction from the construction, and proves that all fractions are reduced.