# Prove that $\gcd(m+m', n+n') = 1$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'm stuck trying to solve this problem:

"Given positive integers $m, n, m', n'$ such as $m/n < m'/n'$ and $m'n - mn' = 1$, we define $$a/b = (m+m')/(n+n').$$ Check that $m/n < a/b < m'/n'$ and prove that $$gcd(a, b) = 1."$$

The way I see it, it must be that $a = m+m'$ and $b = n+n'$. But I'm not sure how to prove the $gcd(a,b) = 1$ part. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\ (m+m')\,n - m\,(n'+n) = m'n-mn'= 1$,

Comment: Oh, now I see it. Thanks!

Comment: That wasn't a hint, but +1 anyway since you've helped the OP!

Answer (score 0):

It is clear when viewed as a column operation preserving a *determinant*

$$\left|\begin{array}{} m'+m & m\\ n'\,+\,n & n\end{array}\right|\,=\,\left|\begin{array}{} m' & m\\ n' & n\end{array}\right|\qquad $$

**Note** $ $ This [Farey mediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Farey_neighbours) operation has a natural geometric interpretation as a change of basis:

$\quad \dfrac{m}n,\,\dfrac{m'}{n'}\,$ are Farey adjacent  $\!\iff\!  \begin{align}u &= (n,\ m)\\ v &= (n',m')\end{align}$ are a basis of $\,\Bbb Z^2$ $\!\iff\! |\det(u,v)| = 1$

This has a pretty proof via Pick's Area theorem, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27637/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39671/242). The mediant operation yields the diagonal $\,u\!+\!v\,$ of the fundamental parrallelogram with sides $\,u,v\,$ and we obtain another basis by replacing one side by the diagonal, i.e. $\, u,v \to u\!+\!v,\,v$, depicted below (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)))

$\qquad\qquad $ [image]