# Third proof of theorem 28-29 from GH Hardy's Theory of Number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integer-lattices, farey-sequences

[image]

After a few discussions regarding lattices, fundamental lattices and some of their properties, the author writes this proof of a theorem regarding Farey series. I don't really see how some of his claims follow. They're not so obvious to me. I get  how only visible points inside or on the boundary represent all the fractions of the Farey series, but how does he know that there won't be any representative point inside the triangle OPP' ? Also, what about the case where the two consecutive fractions are $\frac{0}{1}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ ? We don't have a triangle in that case.

Comment: Is that why he said "or the joint PP'" ? For the case that P coincides with O?

Comment: The points $(0,0), (1,0), (n,1)$ do form a triangle. That there's no Farey point in the triangle $OPP'$ or on the line segment joining $P$ and $P'$ follows from the "consecutive", since a point in that triangle or on the join would lie between $\frac{h}{k}$ and $\frac{h'}{k'}$.

Comment: Is it because if a fraction $\frac{h''}{k''}$ existed in the triangle OPP' , then the line connecting this fraction would have slope $\frac{h''}{k''}$ which must be less than the slope of OP', $\frac{h'}{k'}$ and greater than the slope of OP,  $\frac{h}{k}$ but which would then mean that $\frac{h}{k}$ and $\frac{h'}{k'}$ aren't consecutive? @DanielFischer

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: There's a beautiful proof by [Pick's Area Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39671/242)