# Multiplicative inverses for elements in field

Tags: finite-fields

How to compute multiplicative inverses for elements in any simple (not extended) finite field? I mean an algorithm which can be implemented in software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unit group of the finite field of order $q$ is a cyclic group of order $q-1.$ Thus, for any $a \in \mathbb{F}_q^{\times},$ $$a^{-1} = a^{q-2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

In both cases one may employ the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to compute inverses. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34529/euclidean-algorithm-to-find-the-gcd/34588#34588) for an example. Alternatively, employ repeated squaring to compute $\rm\:a^{-1} = a^{q-2}\:$ for $\rm\:a \in \mathbb F_q^*\:,\:$ which is conveniently recalled by writing the exponent in [binary Horner form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26722/calculating-ab-mod-c/26738#26738) A useful reference is Knuth: [TAoCP, vol 2: Seminumerical Algorithms.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201896842)

Answer (score 2):

If 'simple' means a prime field $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ to you, then, given an integer $x$ coprime to $p$, you simply need to find an integer $y$ such that $xy\equiv1\pmod{p}.$
Look up the paragraph of *multiplicative inverses* in the [wikipedia page on Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)