# Will some $m$ and $n$ always exist for $m(coprime_1)-n(coprime_2)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

That is, is it guaranteed that, given any $2$ numbers, $p$ and $q$, such that $(p,q)=1$, there will exist $m$ and $n$ so that $mp-nq=1$?

It *seems*  like there should be, but it would be nice to have a proof without much abstract algebra used.

Comment: The use of the (extended) Euclidean algorithm to find the coefficients giving a GCD of two integers [has been discussed more than once before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34529/euclidean-algorithm-to-find-the-gcd).  This special case (GCD is 1) is not (IMHO) special enough to warrant duplication.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. 
Called *[Bezout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout_identity)*.

It says slightly more generally that for all $a,b\in\Bbb Z\ \exists x,y\in\Bbb Z:\ xa+yb=(a,b)\ $  where $(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor.
And the proof relies on identifying the element of *minimal* absolute value among all elements of the form $xa+yb$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by the [Bezout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout_identity) for the gcd (special case gcd $=1).$ Below is a simple proof by induction. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/23500) for a more conceptual proof, which lends greater insight into the essence of the matter.

**Theorem** $\rm\ \ gcd(m,n) = j\,m + k\,n\ $ for some $\rm\,j,k\in\Bbb Z.$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on $\rm\, m\!+\!n.\:$ Trivial if $\rm\,m\,$ or $\rm\,n = 0,\:$ or if $\rm\,m = n.\:$ Else, wlog, $\rm\,m > n > 0.\,$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm\ \ gcd(m,n) &=&\,\rm gcd(m\!-\!n,n)\quad&&\text{by Lemma below}\\
&=&\,\rm j\, (m\!-\!n) + k\, n\quad&&\text{by induction (applies since}\rm\: (m\!-\!n)\!+\!n < m\!+\!n)\\
&=&\,\rm j\,m + (k\!-\!j)\, n\quad&&{\bf QED}\end{eqnarray}$$

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ gcd(m\!-\!n,n) = gcd(m,n)$

**Proof** $\ $ If $\rm\:c\,|\,n\:$ then $\rm\:c\,|\,m\!-\!n\iff c\,|\,m.\:$ Thus $\rm\,m\!-\!n,n\,$ and $\rm\,m,n\,$ have the same set $\rm\,C\,$ of common divisors $\rm\,c,\,$ hence they have the same *greatest* common divisor (= max $\rm\, C).$

**Remark** $\ $ By interpreting the inductive step procedurally, one easily derives a very simple [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500) to compute the Bezout linear representation of the gcd.

Comment: I now realise I need to read more about number theory before I can appreciate the proof, so I'll leave both answers unaccepted until then.

Comment: @Alyosha I'm happy to elaborate. What is not clear?