# What can you do with rational solutions to linear equations?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'm currently doing a project and for part of it I've been looking at rational solutions to linear eqautions in two vaiables, i.e. $ax+by=c$.
I'd like to add a bit about what we can use these types of equations and their solutions for but can't find anything on the internet.  Surely there's more to them than just finding $x$ and $y$.  Are there any interesting uses for these types of equations?

Comment: Do you mean rational or integer solutions? You say rational, but Diophantine equations only admit integer solutions.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, its primarily the rational solutions I'm interested in.

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c) or this [link](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51595.html). See rational solutions admit integers solutions too. And to find rational solutions its easy, just isolate one of the variables.

$y=\frac{c-ax}{b} \quad (b \ne 0)$, so the ordered solution pair is

$$(x,\frac{c-ax}{b}) \quad (b \ne 0)$$

Comment: If $b=0$, $y$ can be anything and $x=\frac{c}{a} \quad (a \ne 0)$. If $a$ and $b$ are $0$, so $x$ and $y$ can be anything.