# How to factor integers in a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices

I saw the following riddle:

> You've been giving $\$$100 dollars to buy 100 items. Item A costs $\$$0.56, Item B
>       costs $\$$2.26, and item C costs $\$$0.92.
>       How can you spend all of the money on the 100 items?

Now I know to do the following:

```
.56A + 2.26B + .92C = 100
A + B + C = 100
```

Now doing the following:

```
  .56A + 2.26B + .92C = 100
- .56A -  .56B - .56C = -56
-----------------------------
         1.70B + .36C = 44 // Thanks Arturo Magidin
```

Now that leaves us with 2 unknowns but I need another equation to solve this. I also know that A B and C are all integers. How do I factor that in?

Comment: This is called a diophantine equation.

Comment: Note that your last equations are incorrect: multiplying the second equation by $.56$ gives $.56A + .56 B + .56 C = 56$. Subtracting it from the first equation would give you $44$ on the right hand side, not $.54$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Arturo mentioned in his comment, 
this type of equations is called [linear Diophantine equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_diophantine_equation), nice explanation how they can be solved is given in answers to this
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c).

In your case, you want to find integers $b$ and $c$ such that $170b+36c=4400$, i.e.
$$85b+18c=2200.$$

As you can check at [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=85x%2B18y%3D2200) (and if you learn how to solve linear Diophantine equations, you can try to get the result yourself), all integer solutions are
$$\begin{align*}
b&=18n+10;\\
c&=-85n+75.
\end{align*}
$$
Since you want $b,c\ge 0$, the only possible value is $n=0$. Thus you get $b=10$, $c=75$ and $a=100-b-c=15$.

Comment: Where on wolframalpha did you see `b=18n+10;c=−85n+75`? The link you gave didn't have it.

Comment: Wolframalpha writes in the part _integer solutions_ $x=2(9n+5)$, $y=-5(17n-15)$, $n\in\mathbb Z$. After multiplying these you get the above results.

Answer (score 1):

Given the tags [linear-algebra] and [matrices], this is what you need to do:

1. Solve the problem using matrices in the usual way; since you have two equations in three unknowns, you will have infinitely many solutions. Express them in terms of a parameter.
2. Find a value of the parameter that makes all variables into positive integers.

Here we have:
$$\begin{align*}
56A + 226B + 92C &= 10000\\
A + B + C &= 100
\end{align*}$$
so we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
56 & 226 & 92 & 10000\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 100
\end{array}\right) &\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & 1 & 100\\
28 & 113 & 46 & 5000
\end{array}\right)
&&\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & 1 & 100\\
0 & 85 & 18 & 2200
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & 1 & 100\\
0 & 1 & \frac{18}{85} & \frac{440}{17}
\end{array}\right)
&&\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & \frac{67}{85} & \frac{1260}{17}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{18}{85} & \frac{440}{17}
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$

So the solutions are:
$$\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{1260}{17} - \frac{67}{85}t\\
B &= \frac{440}{17} - \frac{18}{85}t\\
C&= t
\end{align*}$$
Now find the values of $t$ for which all three quantities are positive integers.

Comment: I just have to go through each way? What if there are 1000 items? and so on?

Comment: @qwertymk: You don't "have" to do anything; if you want to *solve the problem*, then you need to come up with a method, and which method you use will depend on which tools you wish to employ. The problem can be solved using congruences as well, but I assumed from your choice of tags that you are expected/required to solve it using matrices/systems of linear equations. If so, this is the way of doing it. If the number of items changes, the *only thing* that you would need to change is the last entry of the first matrix, and fix the computations on the last column. Then determine $t$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ \ 170\ b + 36\ c\ =\ 4400\ \iff\ 85\ b + 18\ c\ =\ 2200\:,\ $ therefore

$$\rm mod\ 18\!:\ \ b\ \equiv\ \frac{2200}{85}\ \equiv\ \frac{440}{17}\ \equiv\ \frac{8}{-1}\ \equiv\ -8\ \equiv\ 10 $$

Thus $\rm\ \ b\ =\ 10 + 18\ n\ \ $ and  $\rm\ \ c\ = \ \dfrac{2200 - 85\ (10 + 18\ n))}{18}\ =\ 75 - 85\ n $

Now $\rm\ b \ge 0\ \Rightarrow\ n\: \ge\: 0\ $ and $\rm\ c\ge 0\ \Rightarrow\ n\:\le\:0\:.\:$ Thus $\rm\ n\:=\:0\ $ so $\rm\ b,\:c\ =\ \ldots\ $ hence $\rm\ a\ =\ \ldots$