# Solving $217 x \equiv 1 \quad \text{(mod 221)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am given the problem:

Find an integer $x$ between $0$ and $221$ such that
$$217 x \equiv 1 \quad \text{(mod 221)}$$

How do I solve this? Unfortunately I am lost.

Comment: Look up the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). They are useful for solving this type of problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this special case, you can multiply the congruence by $-1$ and you'll get
$$4x\equiv 220 \pmod{221}.$$
(Just notice that $-217 \equiv 4 \pmod{221}$ and $-1\equiv220\pmod{221}$.)

This implies that $x\equiv 55 \pmod{221}$ is a solution. (And since $\gcd(4,221)=1$, there is only one solution modulo $221$.)

---

In general, for questions of this type you can use extended Euclidean algorithm see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem).

You can find some examples at this site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c).

Comment: can you elaborate on we get from multiplying by -1, to $4x \equiv 220 \text{(mod 221)}$? I see the parenthesis, but can say that more explicitly? having a little trouble following

Comment: $-217$ and $4$ are congruent modulo $221$, hence we can replace $-217$ by $4$ without changing the validity of the congruence relation. The same is true for $-1$ and $220$.

Comment: Although in this case we were able to make a guess which made finding the solution easy, it is useful to learn a method how to do this in general.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/euclid-wallis.html):
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&54&4\\
\hline
\color{red}{1}&0&1&\color{red}{-54}&217\\
0&\color{green}{1}&-1&\color{green}{55}&-221\\
\color{red}{221}&\color{green}{217}&4&\color{blue}{1}&0
\end{array}
$$
we get that $\color{green}{55\cdot217}\color{red}{-54\cdot221}=\color{blue}{1}$. Thus, $x=55\pmod{221}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ {\rm\ mod}\,\ 221\!:\quad\ \dfrac{1}{217}\equiv\dfrac{-220}{-4}\equiv 55$

${\rm mod}\,\ 4n\!+\!1\!:\ \ \dfrac{1}{4n\!+\!1\!-\!4}\equiv \dfrac{-4n}{-4}\equiv n\quad $  [above is case $\,n = 55$]

${\rm mod}\,\ an\!+\!1\!:\,\ \dfrac{1}{an\!+\!1\!-\!a}\equiv \dfrac{-an}{-a}\equiv n\quad $ [above is case $\,a=4$]

i.e. $\ \ \  an\!+\!1\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, (-a)n\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\  n \equiv \dfrac{1}{-a\ }\equiv \dfrac{1}{-a + k(an\!+\!1)}$