# How to find integer solutions for indeterminate equations in $Ax + By = C$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I would like to find some positive integer solutions to an equation in the form $Ax + By = C.$ I have already seen some methods for doing this, such as the one outlined in [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c.).

What I am interested in is the method shown [here](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/numberTheory/indeterminateEquations.htm). The first example is the one I was looking at. I can follow it up to fig [1.2]. I don't understand what the author means by "Reducing the right-hand side to integers and fractions." I would greatly appreciate some help in understanding this process. Also, is there a name that I can Google for the method used in this article? Thanks.

Comment: It's called a *mixed fraction*. $$\dfrac{4238 - 97y}{95} = 44 \ \ \dfrac{58}{95} - (1 \ \ \dfrac{2}{95})y$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a funny way to call a pretty elementary arithmetic operation:
$$\frac{4238-97y}{95}=\frac{44\cdot 95+58-(95y)-2y}{95}=\frac{44\cdot 95}{95}-\frac{95y}{95}+\frac{58-2y}{95}=$$
$$=44-y+\frac{58-2y}{95}$$

Comment: This is integer division with remainder en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Division_with_remainder.  Now for integer solutions you need $2y \equiv 58 \pmod {95}$ or $y=29+95t$ for some integer $t$ as is shown on the page OP linked to.

Comment: Yup, yet the OP just asked about the process the page he linked to was carrying out. Apparently, and hopefully,  he can follow the rest of the argument