# How to find all the positive integral solutions of $5x+7y=100$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How to find the number of all the positive integral solutions and the solutions itselves of $$5x+7y=100?$$

Please help me!!

Comment: $5|100$ what you may conclude from this observation?

Comment: You said "positive integral values". Your equation tells a lot. What did you try ?

Comment: You should later post a question about solving $5x+7y=101$ so that we can explain the whole method of solving equations $ax+by=c$ in the integers.

Comment: Then $5 \cdot 3 + 7 \cdot (-2) = 1$ might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

positive integral means that positive and integer right?because $5$ and $7$ are coprime,that means that $100$ is represented by sum  of two number,which one  of them is divisible by $5$ and $7$,one of possible solution is $30+70$,which is equal  to exactly $100$, or  $x=6$ and $y=10$,could you found others?

EDITED:

second is just $35+65$

there $35$ is divisible by $5$ and $7$

that means that $y=5$ and $x=13$

generally  $x=(100-7*y)/5$

how much positive integer of $y$ is so that $(100-7*y)$ is divisble by $5$ and leaves $x$ positive?

clearly $y$ is positive number,which is multiply of $5$

Comment: Is there infinitely many such $x,y?$

Comment: How to find all the positive integral solutions of:is there infinity positive numbers which satisfy it?also positive and integer?

Comment: thanks very much,good lucks

Answer (score 6):

Assume we have $5x+7y=100$. Let us solve for the variable with the smallest coefficient $x=20-\frac{7y}{5}$. This means that $\frac{7y}{5}$ is integer. Therefore $y=5y_2$ for some integer $y_2$.

Plugging this into the original equation we get $x=20-7y_2$. You see now, that for every integer you put in $y_2$ you get an integer value for $x$, and an integer value for $y=5y_2$ that satisfy the equation $5x+7y=100$.

Since we want positive solutions you can put $y_2>0$ such that $20-7y_2>0$, i.e. $20/7>y_2$. So, $0<y_2\leq 2$.

We have then two possibilities: $y_2=1$ or $y_2=2$, for which we get $y=5$, or $y=10$ respectively. The corresponding values for $x$ are $x=13$, or $6$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $$5x+7y=100$$ also $x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$ie you get the inequalities $$5x\le100$$ or $$x\le20$$ similarly $$y\le14.28$$
Now $$x=\frac{100-7y}{5}$$ which means $5$ divides $7y$. The only values satisfying for $y$ are $$y=0,5,10$$ and is then bounded by the inequality.

Comment: how do you insert greater than or equal to in latex. please help me.

Comment: I have edited your post to include $\le$, $\ge$. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I find personally the [list of symbols on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) very useful when looking for a particular symbol.

Comment: You just type \le for $\le$ and \ge for $\ge$ 8for @surajM.S

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Since $\,5x+7y\,$ is *linear* in $\,x,y,\,$ the general solution of $\,5x+7y=100\,$ is the sum of any particular solution, e.g. $\,(x,y)=(20,0),\,$ plus the general solution solution of the associated homogeneous equation $\,5x+7y = 0,\,$ which is $\,(x,y)=(-7n,5n).\,$ Summing them gives the general solution  $\,(x,y) = (20,0)+(-7n,5n) = (20-7n,5n).\,$ Now $\,5n > 0\!\iff\! n\ge 1,\,$ and $20-7n>0\!\iff\! n\le2.$

Answer (score 1):

$5x+7y=100~\implies 5|y$
$y$ is limited to 14 on the upper side. So, we are left with only $y=5,10$
When,$y=5$,we can have a solution,i.e.,$x=13$
Also,$y=10$,we can have a soluton,i.e.,$x=6$

Answer (score 0):

$5x \gt0$  so $x=1,2,3,4,5,\ldots $
careful about $5x$  and 100 both are 5q ---> so 7y must be 5K too
then put $y=0,5,10$ (not more because $7y$ must be less or equal to $100$)
so 
check them to find $x $

Answer (score 0):

Since $5 \mid 100$, we know that $5$ must divide $5x +7y$ and that therefore $5$ must divide $7y$. Since $5$ and $7$ are coprime, only multiples of $5$ as $y$ will suffice, and since $15 \cdot 7>100$ and both $x,y$ are integral and positive, only $y=5,10$ are solutions.

We have now shown that $(13,5)$ and $(6,10)$ are the only solutions.

Edit: $(20,0)$ can also be a solution if you consider  $0$ a positive number

Answer (score 0):

As $(5,7)=1$ we would definitely have some $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $5x+7y=1$

we see that $5(3)+7(-2)=1$ i.e., $5(300)+7(-200)=100$

Now if $ax_1+by_1 = c$ is any solution, then all solutions are of the form
$$x = x_1 - r\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)},\qquad y = y_1 + r\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}$$
we have $(5,7)=1$ so any solution would be of the form

$x=300-7r$ and $y=-200+5r$

We want solutions to be positive which means that we want $7r<300$ and $5r>200$

i.e., $r<43$ and $r>40$ i.e., $r\in \{41,42\}$

For $r=41$ we would have :

$x=300-287=13; y=-200+215=5$ i.e., $(x,y)=(13,5)$

For $r=42$ we would have :

$x=300-294=6; y=-200+220=10$ i.e., $(x,y)=(6,10)$

So, only positive solutions are $(13,5)$ and $(6,10)$.

If you consider $0$ to be positive then $(20,0)$ would also be a solution you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for pointing out my mistake, postmortem. 
Through diophantine equation, I get

$$x = 300 -7r,$$ 
for all $r-$ integers, 
$$y = -200 +5r $$

To solve the inequalities above. So, to get the positive solution, for the above inequalities,

we need to set certain boundaries such that, 
$r\ge40$ , and $r<42$,

sorry for my mistake, due to I am having fever. Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake.

Reference：
[How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c)

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Okay thanks alot, dantopa. I will learn to use it.

Comment: These edits should help. Again, welcome.