# Solve Linear Diophantine $12x+18y = 54$

Tags: diophantine-equations

### What is asked?

As the title suggests I'm trying to solve a very simple Linear Diophantine Equation: $$12x + 18y = 54$$

Also find an expression for all integer solutions

### What have I done?

- Firstly, I know that $ax+by = c$ has a solution $\iff$ gcd$(a,b \space | \space c)$
- Secondly, I need to compute the gcd $ (18,12) = 6 $

$$18 = 1 \cdot 12 + 6$$
$$12 = 2 \cdot 6 + 0$$

Therefore, gcd(18,12) = 6

- Does 6 | 54? Yes. Therefore the equation has integral solutions.
- Okay, all good so far. But it's the next stage that sort of stumps me.

So we can rearrange to get: $$6 = 18 - (1 \cdot 12)$$

Now do I multiply through 9? Whats the next step? I also need to do a generalised form for all integers.

I have seen this thread [How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c), and it is very helpful but every time I come up with a value for $x$ and $y$ it always makes the LHS = 0. But it obviously needs to = 54.

$$\text{Thank you!}$$

Comment: When I was young, I tried to find two points , then represent the solution as linear equation

Comment: Yes you multpily by $9$. You arrive at $-12\cdot9+18\cdot9=54$ from where $(x,y)=(-9,9)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to simplify to
$$2x+3y=9$$
Modulo 3, $$2x\equiv 0\pmod 3\implies x\equiv 0 \pmod 3\implies x:=3m$$ and modulo 2 $$y \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \implies y:=2n+1$$
$$6m+3(2n+1)=9=6(m+n)+3\implies m+n=1\implies m=1-n$$
Hence, $$x=3-3n,y=2n+1$$ for all integral $n$ is the family of solutions.

Comment: Can this method always be used to find the family of solutions of Diophantine Equations?

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much got it, you just need to equate coefficients with the Diophantine equation, so the multiplier of 12 becomes $x$ and likewise, the multiplier of 18 becomes $y$

  $6=1\times18-1\times12$

  $54=9\times18-9\times12$ (multiplying by 9)

$ \Rightarrow x=-9, y=9$ (equating coefficients)
that's your solution

Answer (score 0):

First you simplify.

$$12x + 18y = 54 \iff 2x + 3y = 9$$

Next you find **a** solution.

$$(x_0,y_0) = (0, 3)$$

I found that solution by seeing that $3 \mid 9$ and took advantage of that by letting $x=0$. Another method is to solve for, say, $x$: $\quad x=\dfrac{9-3y}{2}$. So we need $9-3y \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ which simplifies to $y \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. Then  $y=1$ will give us $$(x_0, y_0)=(3, 1)$$.

There is a formula for the general solution that I always forget. This is what I do.

\begin{align}
   2x + 3y &= 9 \\
   2x_0 + 3y_0 &= 9\\
\hline
   2(x-x_0) + 3(y-y_0) &= 0 \\
   2(x-x_0) &= -3(y-y_0)
\end{align}

Clearly $x-x_0$ needs to be a multiple of $3$, lets say $x-x_0 = 3t$

Substituting and solving, you get

$$(x,y) = (x_0 + 3t, y_0-2t)$$

So $$(x,y) = (3t, 3-2t)$$ is one solution and $$(x,y) = (3 + 3t, 1-2t)$$ is another solution. Either one will work.