# Finding minimum difference between two linear functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization, analytic-geometry

Given two functions of the form $y = m_1x + c_1$ and $y = m_2x + c_2$ where $m_1,m_2,c_1,c_2$ are positive integers. How to find the absolute minimum difference between the two functions for positive integral values of $x$?

e.g. for $y_1=10x+1$ and $y_2=3x+5$ the absolute minimum difference is $0$ for $x_1=1$ and $x_2=2$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ corresponds to $y_1$ and $y_2$ respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically asking whether you can find positive integers $x_{1,2}$ such that
$$m_1x_1+c_1=m_2x_2+c_2$$
which is the same as
$$m_1x_1-m_2x_2=c_2-c_1.$$
If such positive integers exist, then the minimum is zero.

If not, you want to find smallest $d$ (smallest in absolute value) such that 
$$m_1x_1-m_2x_2=c_2-c_1+d$$
has a solution.

The equation of the form 
$$m_1x_1-m_2x_2=A$$
is a [linear Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Diophantine_equation) and there is a simple way of saying whether there is a solution: It is true if and only if $\gcd(m_1,m_2)\mid A$. Solutions can be found using [extended Euclidean algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

This only gives you a solution $x_{1,2}\in\mathbb Z$. But since $m_{1,2}>0$, the solutions will be in fact non-negative.

See also:

- [How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c)

The example you gave in the question leads to the Diophantine equation $$10x_1-3x_2=4,$$ which indeed has solution $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$.