# Further question on Diophantine equations of form $ax+by=c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have read this nice post:

[How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c)

and it all makes sense, but was wondering if one can apply this only if $a > 0, b > 0, c > 0$?

Consider for example:

$ 13x - 23y = -4 $

$ Gcd(13,23) = 1 $ so I'm not sure there is straight applicability of the method derived in the post mentioned above. However, this equation has clearly solutions, i.e., (for $x=5,y=3$):

$ 13 * 5 - 23 * 3 = 65 - 69 = -4 $.

So how to tackle such equations if we have $gcd(a,b) = 1$ ?

Comment: Solve the equation $13x+23y=4$ and adjust the signs of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Changing of sign won't change fact that gcd(x,y) = 1 still...

Answer (score 1):

Solve $13x+23y=4$ and adjust the signs of $x$ and $y$.

Using the algorithm described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021)
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&1&3&3\\\hline
1&0&1&-1&4&-13\\
0&1&-1&2&-7&23\\
23&13&10&3&1&0
\end{array}
$$
we get the answer
$$
13(-7)+23(4)=1
$$
multiply by $4$
$$
13(-28)+23(16)=4
$$
add $13(23)+23(-13)=0$
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{13(-5)+23(3)=4}
$$
changing signs gives
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{13(5)-23(3)=-4}
$$