# Proving that there is no integer solution to $3996x-3071y=-482$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, congruences

So i just got a hang of congruence but I am unable to solve this
also how does one find all integers solution for $1566x - 232y = 116$ such that $0 \leq x,y \leq 100$

Comment: It is a particular case of a very classical issue: see for example (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/20717)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ (3996,3071)=37$$ which  does not divide $$482$$

$$108x-83y=\dfrac{482}{37}$$

The left hand side is an integer unlike the right hand side.

As $(1566,232,116)=58$

$$1566x-232y=116\iff27x-4y=2 \iff 27(x-2)=4(y-13)\iff y-13=\dfrac{27(x-2)}4$$

As $(27,4)=1,4|(x-2)\iff x=4m+2$ where $m$ is any integer

Consequently, $y-13=\dfrac{27(x-2)}4=?$

Comment: what about the other one how should one approach

Comment: @Kiterunner, Please find the updated answer

Comment: Thanks! can you explain me $289(4^{2016})-1000$ is divisible by 68? How does one do without calculator?

Comment: ?? what would be 27(x-2) still cant get? @lab bhattacharjee