# How to find all integer solution of an equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

I want to find whether a given equation like $2x + 5y = 27$ (tow variable linear equation) have integer solution for $x$ and $y$, $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$.

If yes how to find it?

And In my actual question i have to find a solution such that $x+y$ is minimized.

Is there a particular method for this or we have to check for all value?

Comment: Probably been asked, and answered, a dozen times on this website, but maybe not so easy to find. Suggest searching questions tagged "linear diophantine eqns".

Comment: I just need method for this i am implementing this in c++ program so calculation will no matter..

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995686/proving-that-there-is-no-integer-solution-to-3996x-3071y-482

Comment: So, Poojan, did you try the search I recommended?

Comment: I am doing if i will find solution i needed i delete this question thanks..

Comment: No, Poojan, if you find the solution you need, post a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: [How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c?rq=1) The mathematical answer to your question lies there, although I suspect it will be somewhat more complicated to efficiently implement this in code.