# Prove that the equation $18x+42y=22$ has no integer solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you help me to prove? Should I prove it  by contradiction and suppose that $x$, y are solutions ?

Comment: What integer divides the LHS but not the RHS, and what can you conclude  from that?

Comment: This is a very classical **diophantine equation** ; I am surprised that answers don't refer to sites like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/20717) ; ) where one can find explanations/proofs

Comment: It would be nice if, in the future, you let us know what you know about the problem, or what you have tried. At the very least, you could start by reducing to $9x+21y=11$, for example. It would also be helpful to know what sort of class this is for...

Comment: @JeanMarie Surely because a proof of this direction of the equivalence is quite trivial (unlike the opposite), so there is no need for such.

Comment: I reduced to 9x+21y=11 then because left side can be divided by 3 and right cannot I assumed there was no solution but when it comes to maths I never trust my self :c thanks for advice, I will do better next time ^

Answer (score 8):

$ax+by=c$ has solution in the integers if and only if $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$ divides $c$. Hence no solution in your example.

(In particular, $18x+42y$ is multiple of $3$, while $22$ not.)

Comment: Thank you thank you Paolo!!~

Answer (score 4):

Notice that for integers $x$ and $y$, the left-hand side is always a multiply of $3$; but $22$...

$$18x+42y=22 \iff \color{blue}{3} \left( 6x+14y \right) = 22$$

Comment: I appreciate!! Thank you alot

Answer (score 1):

Observe that LHS is a multiple of 3 but RHS is not a multiple of 3 so there exist rational solutions but not integral solutions