# How to find all integer pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation $21x+47y=1$ without using modular arithmetic?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Find all integer pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy the following equation:
>   $$
> 21x+47y=1.
> $$

I know the solution with modular arithmetic: 
\begin{align}
0x + 5y &= 1 \pmod{21} \\
   5y   &= -20 \pmod{21}\\
 y = -4 \pmod{21} &\Longleftrightarrow y = -4 + 21c \\
21x + 47(-4 + 21c) &= 1\\ 
21x &= 189 - 21 * 47c \\
  x &= 9 - 47c. \\
\end{align}

Therefore 
$$(x, y) = (9 - 47c, -4 + 21c)$$

Is there a way to do this without modular arithmetic? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use LaTeX formatting so your question is readable! Why do you want to do this without modular arithmetic?

Comment: it is the same kind of question you have asked some minutes ago !

Comment: Please Stop. You have asked two same questions today. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067728/prove-that-the-equation-18x42y-22-has-no-integer-solution.

Comment: I feel like I will never be able to use stackexchange correctly :o I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\operatorname{gcd}(21,47)=1$ so there is a solution, by [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). Suppose $(x,y)$ is such a solution. Then note
\begin{align}
21x+47y=1&\iff21x+21\cdot47+47y-21\cdot47=1\\
&\iff 21(x+47)+47(y-21)=1
\end{align}