# Diophantine equation with negative value

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Find the general solution to 10x -8y = 42

Okay, so do I find gcd(10, -8)? (this is clearly 2 but I need to use euclid's algorithm so I can work backwards to find the general solution)

If I do that I get

10 = -8(1) + 18
-8 = 18(1) - 26
18 = -26(1) + 44
-26 = 44

so this isn't going to work as every line gets further away rather than closer to a solution.

Should I just find gcd(10, 8)

10 = 8(1) + 2
8  = 4(2) + 0 
 gcd = 2
But then how do I accommodate for it being a negtive y?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c?rq=1) may help.

Comment: IMHO, always start by reducing a linear equation to its simplest form, by dividing through by any common factor. In this case $5x-4y=21$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest if you just start with $10$ and $8$ then be careful with the signs when you are working out $x$ and $y$.

However it is also possible to work with negative numbers as long as you make sure the reminder when dividing by $b$ is always from $0$ to $|b|-1$.  (So your first step with remainder $18$ was wrong.)  For $10$ and $-8$ the Euclidean algorithm would be
$$\eqalign{
  10&=(-1)(-8)+2\cr
  -8&=(-4)(2)\cr}$$
and since the remainder is zero, that's it.  Working backwards you have
$$2=10(1)-(-8)(-1)$$
which is
$$2=10(1)-8(1)\ .$$
Multiplying by $21$ gives
$$42=10(21)-8(21)$$
and comparing with $10x-8y=42$ gives a possible solution $x=21$, $y=21$.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but for anyone who just wants a quick and easy fix, just convert 10x - 8y = 42 to 10x + 8(-y) = 42, then set another variable, like z equal to -y. The equation now becomes 10x + 8z = 42. Solve for x and z, and then just replace z with -y.