# Is there a shortcut for solving $ax-by=c$ when a,b,c are relatively prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

I know [how to find solutions for linear Diophantine equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c?rq=1)  like $ax-by=c$, but is there a shortcut when I already know that (a,b,c) are mutually prime?

Even if there isn't a *conceptual* shortcut, is there a nicer or briefer  way to describe the algorithm in this special case?

Comment: No, because the general problem is trivially reducible to the case when $a,b$ are coprime.

Comment: Does the fact that I know c is also mutually prime help matters at all?

Comment: Generally it is solvable iff $\,\gcd(a,b)\mid c.\ $ So your case is solvable iff $\,\gcd(a,b) = 1,\,$ and the same method of solution works for all $\,c\neq 0.\ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only $a$ and $b$ have to  be coprime to ensure there are solutions. You begin with solving $u_oa+v_0b=1$ (*Bézout's identity*) with the *extended Euclidean algorithm*. Then
$$x_0=cu_0,\quad y_0=-cv_0$$
is a solution.

As  all solution to *Bézout's identity* are
$$x=x_0+kb,\quad y=y_0-ka\quad(k\in\mathbf Z),$$
all solutions of the given equation have the form
$$x=x_0+kb, \quad y=y_0+ka.$$