# A problem regarding a Linear Diophantine Equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

A pen costs £11 ,  A notebook costs £13. In how many ways can you spend exactly £1000 ?

Although it is really basic number theory, I am really having a tough time understanding it . I don't need an answer, I need a thorough  explanation. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Find one way to spend 1000. Then find the systematic way to get from that one way to all the other ways. Then you'll be able to work out the number of ways.

Comment: Take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a linear Diophantine equation. From [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) on Diophantine equations

> [A linear Diophantine, $ax+by=c$] equation has a solution (where $x$ and $y$ are integers) if and only if $c$ is a multiple of the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Moreover, if ($x$, $y$) is a solution, then the other solutions have the form $(x + kv, y − ku)$, where $k$ is an arbitrary integer, and $u$ and $v$ are the quotients of $a$ and $b$ (respectively) by the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Back to your problem, the equation you want to solve is $11x + 13y = 1000$ where x and y are the number of pens and notebooks respectively you will buy. Now the greatest common divisor of $11$ (plays the role of $a$ in the equation on Wikipedia) and $13$ (plays the role of $b$ in the equation on Wikipedia) is $1$ since they are both prime. $1000$ (plays the role of $c$ in the equation on Wikipedia) is clearly a multiple of $1$, so this equation has a solution.

Now an easy way to find one solution is through guessing. $y=\frac{1}{13}(1000-11y)$

$x=0 \rightarrow y=76.923... \notin \mathbb{Z}$

$x=1 \rightarrow y=76.077... \notin \mathbb{Z}$

$x=2 \rightarrow y=75.231... \notin \mathbb{Z}$

$x=3 \rightarrow y=74.385... \notin \mathbb{Z}$

$x=4 \rightarrow y=73.538... \notin \mathbb{Z}$

$x=5 \rightarrow y=72.692... \notin \mathbb{Z}$

$x=6 \rightarrow y=71.846... \notin \mathbb{Z}$

$\boxed{x=7 \rightarrow y=71 \in \mathbb{Z}}$

Now that we have $(x,y) = (7,71)$ as a solution, everything of the form $(7+13k,71-11k)$ is a solution. For example with $k=1$, we get $(20,60)$, which upon checking, is also a solution. You also must restrict the value of k so that $x$ and $y$ are both positive, since one cannot buy a negative quantity of an item at a store.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts ;)

Answer (score 0):

$$11x+13y=500(13-11)$$

$$\iff11(x+500)=13(500-y)$$

$\implies11$ must divide $500-y\implies y=500-11t$ where $t$ is any integer

Clearly, $500-11t\ge0\iff t\le ?$

Similarly $x=13t-500\ge0\iff t\ge?$

Answer (score 0):

We want to find all nonnegative integer solutions for

$$11x+13y=1000.$$

First, guess one solution, e.g. $x=7, y=71$. Then generalize

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x=7+13k,\\y=71-11k,\end{array}\;(k\in\mathbb{Z})\right.$$

Finally, count the number of solutions. We have $k=0,1,2,\ldots,6$. So there are $7$ solutions.