# Finding integer solutions in diophantine equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$m, n$ are integers, find all integer solutions of the diphantine equation:

$$nx + (n + 2)y = m$$

where $n$ is odd.

I´ve tried with Euclides but i get this:

$$2m = (n + 2)m - nm$$

I need a hint or something.

Comment: Your equation is linear, so you may try and write it in the form $y = \cdots$ and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diophantine equation $ax+by=c$ has solutions if and only if  $gcd(a,b)|c$.
So for this equation $nx + (n+2)y = m$ to have solution $gcd(n, n+2)|m$ and $gcd(n, n + 2)$ is 1

From the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, given any integers $a$ and $b$ you can find integers $s$ and $t$ such that $$as+bt=gcd(a,b)$$ ($s$ and $t$ may not be unique) where $a = n, b = (n+2)$ and $gcd(a, b)=1$. Now multiply $m$ to both sides. you'll get $n(sm) + (n+2)(tm) = m$, this gives a solution $x=sm$, $y =tm$.

Here is a very [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c) which explains how to get other solutions from this

Comment: I'm sorry, I've corrected my post, $n$ is odd.

Comment: Hey, as gcd of two consecutive odd integers is 1. So, I changed the part gcd(n, n+2) = 2 to gcd(n, n+2) = 1. And other things a bit as now one solution is x = sm and y = tm

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** if $n=2k+1$ then $n+2=2k+3$.

Then 
$$1=2k+1-2k=n-k(n+2-n)=n(1+k)-(n+2)k$$

Multiplying by $m$ you get the solution
$$x_0=m(1+k)\\
y_0=-km$$

Now solve
$$n(x-x_0)+(n+2)(y-y_0)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ 1 = n(\overbrace{x\!+\!y}^{\Large z}) + 2y \iff (z,y)\, =\, \overbrace{(1,(1\!-\!n)/2)}^{\rm particular} + \overbrace{k(-2,n)}^{\rm homogeneous}$

Comment: $\large {\rm by}\ \bmod n\!:\,\ 2y\equiv 1\equiv 1\!-\!n\iff y\equiv  (1\!-\!n)/2 \in\Bbb Z\  \ \, {\rm by}\ n\    \rm odd\ \ $