# Asking for help in problem 4 of section 2.5 of David Burton book

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am self studying Elementary number theory from David Burton Book. While trying exercises of Section 2.5 , I am unable to think about this problem

> If a and b are relatively prime positive integers, prove that Diophantine equation ax-by =c has infinitely many solutions in the positive integers.

Can someone please help in how to solve this problem!!

Comment: Use https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma

Comment: This may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Bezout's Lemma, we have a solution to $ax+by=1$ when $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then:
$$ax-b(-y)=1 $$$$ \implies  ax-b(-y)+kab-kab=1 $$$$\implies a(x+kb)-b(ka-y)=1$$$$\implies a(cx+ckb)-b(cka-cy)=c$$
Now, $k$ can take whatever integral value we want it to take. Thus, we have infinitely many values $aX-bY=c$, where a family of infinitely many solutions are:
$$(X,Y)=(cx+ckb,cka-cy)$$

Comment: but how to prove rigorously that infinitely many X and Y are positive?

Comment: if I apply positivity conditions on X, Y then k>( -b/x ) and k>(y/a) and since x, y are infinitely many solutions of ax+by=c, so I have infinitely many +ve solutions if k >max ( -b/x, y/a) . Is my argument right?

Comment: I didn't understand what you typed above. The way you prove that $X$ and $Y$ are positive infinitely many times is that you make $cka$ and $ckb$ sufficiently large and positive. If $c$ is positive, make $k$ sufficiently large and positive. If $c$ is negative, make $k$ sufficiently large (magnitude) and negative.

Comment: as (cx+ckb), (cka-cy) are solutions so applying positivity conditions on them is both of them must be >0 . Then my previous comment follows. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes @InvisibleMan !

Answer (score 0):

Since $a,b$ are relatively prime we can find integers $u,v$ such that $$au+bv=1.$$

Then $x=cu+tb$ and $y=-cv+ta$ where $t$ can be **any** integer are solutions.