# How do you solve this simultaneous equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Is there some kind of algorithm that I can use to find the exact values for **v, u, e** and **f** so that I can solve for **a** and **b** in the equation below?

```
av + bu = 5

ae + bf = 9
```

If I were to apply random values to **v, u, e and f**, Most of the time, I am able to solve for **a and b**. But there are some times that I am not able to solve for **a and b** because the random values applied to v, u, e and f made the equation unsolvable (Haven't you guys encountered problems like this before where you can't solve for the unkown values of an equation because of its coefficients v,u,e and f?). Is there an exact method that I can use to initialize **v, u, e and f** so a and b is always solvable?

Comment: What are the "best" values?

Comment: Dietrich Burde, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Because you didn't clarify. Integers, real numbers? What are the variables? $a$ and $b$? So $u,v,e,f$ are given constants?

Comment: a and b are just numbers.

Comment: What numbers exactly? Do we have $a,b\in \Bbb Z$, or not? It makes a difference. The question is unclear.

Comment: u,v,e and f are constants.

Comment: *Integer* solutions or not?

Comment: integer solutions

Comment: Then you should add this to your question, which is otherwise not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two linear Diophantine equations. It is well known that $av+bu=5$ is solvable in $\Bbb Z$ if and only if $\gcd(u,v) \mid 5$, and similarly $ae+bf=9$ is solvable if and only if $\gcd(e,f)\mid 9$.

Reference:

[How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c)

Comment: If I were to apply random values to v, u, e and f, Most of the time, I am able to solve for a and b. But there are some times that I am not able to solve for a and b because the random values applied to v, u, e and f made the equation unsolvable (Haven't you guys encountered problems like this before where you can't solve for the unkown values of an equation because of its coefficients v,u,e and f?). Is there an exact method that I can use to initialize v, u, e and f so a and b is always solvable?

Comment: Yes, see the answer. You will not able to solve the first equation if and only if $\gcd(u,v)$ is not dividing $5$, and similarly for the second equation. Note that this includes also the case $u=v=0$, or $e=f=0$.

Comment: Please, what does gcd(u,v)∣5 mean?

Comment: See the reference. For example, $u=2,v=6$, then the gcd is the greatest common divisor, namely $2$, which does not divide $5$. So $\gcd(2,6)\nmid 5$. But $\gcd(20,25)=5$, which divides $5$.