# Solving $2444 = 960x \pmod{2618}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to teach myself modular arithmetic to solve a programming challenge. Basically it needs to solve this kind of system of modular equation,

\begin{align*}
2444 = 960x \pmod{2618}
\end{align*}

except the number is very large.

I know the basic concept of modulo but that is it, I don't even know the term to search on google to help solve me this.

How do you solve for $x$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can search for "solving linear congruences"; there is definitely an algorithm, which is very similar to the algorithm for calculating greatest common divisors.

Comment: You essentially want to find solutions to the equation $960x + 2618y = 2444$. [Here is how to do that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c/1841863).

Comment: While you may be interested in a "programming challenge", the programming tag is, quote, "For mathematical questions related to programming, and questions where a computer-aided solution is strongly suggested.   A strong connection with a mathematical topic is needed to make programming questions on-topic." That is not what this equation is about.

Comment: The [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) is useful in solving these sort of equations. There are many implementations on the web and on this site. The one I use is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021).

Answer (score 2):

1. Since for each $n\in\mathbb N$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z,$ $$ac\equiv
       bc \pmod{n}\iff a\equiv b \pmod{\frac n{\gcd\left(c,n\right)}},$$ we
   have $$960x \equiv 2444 \pmod{2618} \\\iff 240x \equiv 611
   \pmod{1309}.$$
2. The previous line is equivalent to the system
   $$\begin{align*}
   240x&\equiv 611
   \pmod{7}\\240x&\equiv 611 \pmod{11}\\240x&\equiv611 \pmod{17}.\end{align*}$$
3. Solving it is equivalent to obtaining the $x$-solution of the
   Diophantine equation (a polynomial of which only integer solutions
   are of interest) $$240x+1309y=611.$$
4. Noting that $\gcd(240,1309)=1,$ i.e., $240$ has a multiplicative inverse; continuing from Point $1\dots.$

   Euclidean algorithm:
   $$\begin{align*}
   1309&=5(240)+109\\240&=2(109)+22\\109&=4(22)+21\\22&=1(21)+1
   \end{align*}$$
   Reversing the above equations:
   $$\begin{align*}
   1&=22-1(21)\\&=22-(109-4(22))\\&=5(22)-109\\&=5(240-2(109))-109\\&=5(240)-11(109)\\&=5(240)-11(1309-5(240))\\&=60(240)-11(1309)\end{align*}$$
   In $\mathbb Z_{1309}$, $$\begin{align*}
   1&=60(240)\\240^{-1}&=60.\end{align*}$$ Therefore
   $$960x
   \equiv 2444 \pmod{2618} \\\begin{array}{rcl}
   \qquad\qquad\iff x&\equiv& 60\times 611\\
   &\equiv&8\pmod{1309}.\end{array}$$

Comment: Nice solution. Does step 2 have any relevance to the rest of the solution. I can't seem to find where you use the knowledge obtained in that step.

Comment: @AlanAbraham It appears to derive from the Chinese remainder theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: @egglog Yes, I can see that. I'm just not seeing where it is implemented into the rest of the solution.

Comment: @AlanAbraham I should've been clearer that 2 & 3 are extra-informational points and alternative solution paths. For example, we might continue from Point 3 using continued fractions. I think the extended Euclidean algorithm is the most straightforward.